# difference of `repaly_votes` and `gossip_vote_txs`

Tags: validator, core-technology, vote-account, core

I am working to understand voting process in Solana. I can't understand the difference of `repaly_votes` and `gossip_vote_txs`. What are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

The replay votes are part of the proposed block to be validated, sent through the shreds protocol, while the gossip vote transactions are sent and fetched through the gossip protocol.

If you're looking in `cluster_info_vote_listener.rs`, they're mainly used to keep track of cluster progress, checking the sum of stake votes on the different forks.  Votes are propagated through these two mechanisms, helping the validator be doubly sure that consensus is progressing.

You can find more information about the validator internals at https://docs.solana.com/validator/anatomy